# Continuous testing using testng or any other framework

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng

One of our application needs a continuous testing

Let's say my sample test class looks like below.

```
Class someClass {

      @Test
      public test_method1() {
              //do something
              //takes one minute to complete execution
      }
      @Test
      public test_method2() {
              //do something
              //takes ten minutes to complete execution
      }
      @Test
      public test_method3() {
              //do something
              //takes one minute to complete execution
      }
}
```

And my testng.xml will look something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="someSuite" parallel="tests">
   <test name="someTest" parallel="methods" thread-count="3">
        <classes>
            <class name="someClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Let's say each of my test methods take different times to complete execution. Suppose test_method1 and test_method3 take 1 minute for completion, and test_method2 will take 10 minutes for completion.

Since each of my test methods needs to be continuously tested, is there a way to run rerun test_method1 and test_method3 as soon as they complete execution, instead of waiting for test_method2 to complete execution. Is there a way to configure this in testng or any other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think so. All the `@Test` methods that get included as part of a TestNG suite xml file execution, are treated as one execution batch. 
Re-running of tests is possible by including a `RetryAnalyzer` implementation (that is subjected to test failures) in the way in which you expect. But if you are looking at the next set of execution happening via CI, then its not going to happen until the current execution runs to completion.